# LinkedIn OAuth : Requesting Authorization token

Tags: javascript, api, linkedin-api

some strange error I'm facing while getting requesting for an Authorization code from linkedIn, I'm following this link [LinkedId Oauth2](https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2-legacy#permissions).
I've built my URL by following this link. But somehow LinkedIn's authentication dialog box is not opening in the browser or any window, it is opening inside network only if we see in the network tab. Sharing screen Shot below for reference.

[image]
If I copy, paste my URL in separate browser tab manually then it is successfully redirecting back to my "Redirect_uri" with an authorization code.
Any idea, why it is being opened inside the network? Sharing my code to in javascript to make API call. This service call is giving me a success response, but the window is not opening in a different tab.

```
login: function() {
var sPath = 'LinkedInDemo/uas/oauth2/authorization';
        $.ajax({
        url: sPath,
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            response_type: "code",
            client_id: "My_clinetId",
            redirect_uri: "https://My_application_url",
            state: "DCEeFWf45A53sdfKef424",
            scope: "r_basicprofile"
        },
        error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            alert('An error occurred... Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information!');
            console.log('errorThrown:');
            console.log(errorThrown);
        },
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#result').html(data);
            alert('Load was performed. Look at the console (F12 or Ctrl+Shift+I, Console tab) for more information! ');
            console.log('data:');
            console.log(data);
        }
    });
```

}

2)2nd issue is like, even though that screen is opening inside network tab, It is not asking for this application wants to access your basic info. find screen shot below.
Can any one suggest why this is not showing application specific window.
With JAVASCRIPT SDk everything is working fine.
But i'm more interested in API call.
Below kinda screen is not comming... 
[image]

help will be appreciated..!!

Answer (score 0):

the first problem is that you arent going to the callback_url. in the developer page on linkedin you have to fill in a callback url, this the url that page will be shown on.

and if i am correct you have to specify the scope inside the implemation of linkedin. where you also specified your client_id.

but if you want a simple pop-up menu for linkedin login, i suggest you use oauth.io.
they make it really easy to setup oauth for social media.

https://coderwall.com/p/ejayxg/javascript-linkedin-social-login-button-for-oauth-io

hopefully this helps you. make sure you check the comment i posted on the page because there is a little typo tho.

Comment: i tried using this, but giving error as Oauth is undefined. Any dependency do i need to implement? also i've used correct redirect url

Comment: at step 4 of the guide you will find the code you need. keep in mind that step 1,2 & 3 have to be correctly executed.

for your own code : you should check if you redirect your user correctly to the redirect_url.

Comment: Yes, my application is redirecting back correctly. But it is not asking like 'Blue leaf' wants to access some of your data, it is directly providing login screen.

Comment: well that screen is outdated, because full_profile does not exists anymore.
i know it will get you the permissions but i do not know if you can place them on the redirected page yourself.